# Как исправить? 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот задача:
Сгенерировать 20 случайных целых чисел в диапазоне от -5 до 4, записать их в ячейки массива. Посчитать сколько среди них положительных, отрицательных и нулевых значений. Вывести на экран элементы массива и посчитанные количества.
Вот текст ошибки:

```
a[i]=int(a[i])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable.
```

Как ето исправить?Большое Спасибо!

```
import random
a=[]
for i in range(20):
      a=random.randint(-5,4)
p=[]
n=[]
z=[]
for i in range(20):
     a[i]=int(a[i])
     for i  in range(0,20,1):
            if(a[i]>0):
                p.append(a[i])
            if(a[i]==0):
                z.append(a[i])
            
            if (a[i]<0):
               n.append(a[i])


print('quantity positive',len(p))
print('quantity negative',len(n))
print('quantity zero',len(z))
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

В 4й строчке вы записываете в переменную "a" целое число:

```
a=random.randint(-5,4)
```

Затем, в 9й строчке вы пытаетесь обратиться к переменной "a" по индексу.

```
a[i]=int(a[i])
```

Но целочисленные переменные не умеют в индекс.
Чтобы всё заработало, вам нужно заменить 4ю строчку на такое:

```
a.append(random.randint(-5,4))
```

А вообще, ваш код не слишком питоничен.
Там где это возможно, рекомендуется вместо циклов использовать списковые включения. Они гораздо более лаконичны, и код с ними становится гораздо проще, чем без них.

Вашу программу можно переписать таким образом:

```
import random


a = [random.randint(-5,4) for _ in range(20)]

p = [i for i in a if i > 0]
n = [i for i in a if i < 0]
z = [i for i in a if i == 0]

print('quantity positive', len(p))
print('quantity negative', len(n))
print('quantity zero', len(z))
```

Как видите, получилось гораздо понятнее, чем у вас.

PS: Признаком хорошего стиля считается ставить пробелы слева и справа от "равно", знаков сравнения и арифметических символов. А также пробел после запятой.

Answer (score 0):

ну фиг знает, зачем ради какой-то питоничности трижды гонять цикл. ИМХО вот это, питоничнее:

```
for i  in range(0,20,1):
            if(a[i]>0):
                p.append(a[i])
            elif(a[i]==0):
                z.append(a[i])
            elif (a[i]<0):
               n.append(a[i])
```

ну, или из логики, последнее условие могло быть просто else

Answer (score 0):

Намного питоничнее и оптимизированее будет такой код:

```
for elem in a:
    if (elem > 0):
        p.append(elem)
    elif (elem == 0):
        z.append(elem)
    elif (elem < 0):
        n.append(elem)
```

Comment: Вот кстати не факт, что это будет работать быстрее чем 3 списковых выражения

Answer (score 0):

Немного оптимизировал код с помощью генераторов (экономия памяти) + z быстро:

```
import random


a = [random.randint(-5,4) for _ in range(20)]

p = sum(1 for i in a if i > 0)
n = sum(i for i in a if i < 0)

print('quantity positive', p)
print('quantity negative', n)
print('quantity zero', 20 - p - n)
```

Comment: Если элементов будет не 20, а 100, или 42, каждый раз в двух местах править? Не проще len(a) взять?