# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable пожалуйста помогите

Tags: python

задачка:
Вова стоит перед лесенкой из
N ступеней. На каждой из ступеней написаны произвольные целые числа. Первым шагом Вова может перейти на первую ступень или, перепрыгнув через первую, сразу оказаться на второй. Также он поступает и дальше, пока не достигнет N-ой ступени. Посчитаем сумму всех чисел, написанных на ступенях через которые прошел Вова.
Требуется написать программу, которая определит оптимальный маршрут Вовы, при котором, шагая, он получит наибольшую сумму.
Программа:

```
l=int(input())
m = input().split()
s=0
i=0
while i <len(m)+1:
    m[i]=int(m[i])
    m[i+1]=int(m[i+1])
    m[i+2]=int(m[i+2])    
    if m[i+1]>0:
        s=s+int(m[i+1])
    else:
        if i!=len(m)-1:
            s=s+max(s[i+1],s[i+2])
        else:
            break
    i=i+1
print(s)
```

Comment: Всегда удивляюсь, почему до SO у Вас руки дошли, а до Google нет? Делаем Ctrl + C Вашей ошибки, делаем Ctrl + V в Google и получаем кучу готовых ответов даже на нашем любимом SO, например, вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/614993/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-int-object-is-not-subscriptable

Comment: Не стоит использовать обращение к элементам списка вида `m[i+1]`. Когда `i` станет равным длине списка `m`, то получите ошибку `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`, т.к. элемента `i+1` в данном списке нет.

Comment: что-то смутно знакомое... Это, кажется, стандартная учебная задача. Вы легко можете найти подробное решение в гугле.

Answer (score 1):

```
s=s+max(s[i+1],s[i+2])
```

У вас же `s` - это одно число. К нему нельзя по индексу обратиться. Возможно, это просто опечатка, и  внутри max должны быть не `s[...]`, а `m[...]`